# Brand link is going back to homepage

Tags: url

Every product has a link to browse other products by the same brand.  When the link is clicked it goes back to the homepage instead of the brand page.

How can I configure it to work?

Browse other 
Earthly Body products

**Website has adult products for sale***
http://www.lubezilla.com/earthly-body-flavored-edible-massage-oil-sampler-5-pack.html

When You click Earthly body is when it goes to the homepage but when we click the logo it works fine.  The Logo has a different URL when clicks which is accurate.  How do I change the brand URL to go there as well?

Answer (score 1):

Link for *earthy body* brand looks like this

```
<a href="/?brand=715 ">Earthly Body</a>
```

This looks like, the design try to trigger a search based on brand and it fails and hence redirecting to home page.

I believe `brand` is a product attribute that is used in in admin side to set brand of a product. If so, you need to make that attribute first visible in search. For this you need to

1. go `Catalog  > Manage Attributes`.
2. Select `brand attribute`
3. Make it visible in search.

For more details you can check this links [LINK 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/using-product-attributes-in-search), [LINK 2](http://mirasvit.com/qa/magento-search-by-manufacturer.html).

An another work around would be make `brand` as a "invisible category" and display that category when the brand link get clicked. For this

1. Create a new category with name "brand" - parent category that holds individual brands
2. Create sub categories for brands. They should be individual brands
3. Associate each product with corresponding sub category.
4. Create logic to display brands. (in frontend)

Whatever my be the way that you adopted, you need to edit the template file that provides brand links according to the way you implemented the brand view. Means you need to change the `href` part like wise.

Hope that makes sense !

Answer (score 0):

As you give home link as brand page  link so it showing home.

Use third party  plugin.which show attribute wise landing

example limk:

http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/free-ajax-layered-navigation-extension.html - FREE

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/attribute-splash-pages.html

http://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html

http://www.manadev.com/magento-shop-by-brand-attribute-splash-pages

http://templates-master.com/magento-brands-and-attributes-pages.html

http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/shop-by-manufacturer-brands-extension.html