# Products page for each brand

Tags: magento-1.7, manufacturer

My main goal is to have pages listting products by each brand available.

From [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35168/brand-link-is-going-back-to-homepage) answer I understood that you can make it possible by serach pages.

All products have 'manufacturer' attribute. To set up search pages you need to make sure that the attrubute is available in search. Then you should be able to access all products by the brand following `example.com/?manufacturer=apple` to see all apple products. Howerver, this link returns the front page.

if I use serach and enter apple it returns a page with url

`http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=apple`

and use the brand filter, select apple the url becomes

`http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?manufacturer=285&q=apple`

Next three links return back to home page, What am I missing here?

`http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?manufacturer=285`

`http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?manufacturer=285`

`http://www.example.com/?manufacturer=285`

Link below returns 404 page

`http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/?manufacturer=285`

Are there other other ways to genertae pages with a list of products by this brands?

Please do not offer extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use the search result url without having the `q` parameter in it (the search query).
But you can use the advanced search url without any `q` parameter.
Just make sure your manufacturer attribute can be used in advanced search.

Then you can use this url:

`http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=285`

Comment: Additionally you can create a custom URL rewrite to use a pretty URL.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show products **based on their brands**, two simple solutions:

1. Create category as per Brand name & add products for that brand only. **(No coding required)**
2. Create CMS pages for brands. Call a phtml inside & load products by apply manufacturer filter. **(Some coding required)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't mind doing coding at all, how can add multiple products to a category at once, without using a pricey plugin preferably? And would not I have to keep adding the new items to these categories as well as set their manufacturer?

Comment: Inside Catalog->Manage Categories->Choose your category->Inside Category Products

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are missing URL param "q" in your urls

```
http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?manufacturer=285
```

It should be like:

```
http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?manufacturer=285&q=apple
```

Below two URL's are incorrect:

```
http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?manufacturer=285

http://www.example.com/?manufacturer=285
```